# Showing joined tables in retrieve function in EF using Code First

Tags: c#, linq

I'm creating a database in EF4.1 Code First. I've got a one-to-many relationship of health forms with health dependents. A health form has 0-5 dependents. When I create the healthform, the dependents table is created for me by using

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BenefitsForm>().HasMany(t => t.Dependents).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

However, when I use the retrieve method:

```
return context.BenefitsForm;
```

it does not display the Dependents table join, only the BenefitsForms. How can I get it to show the BenefitsForm table linked with Dependents table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the `Include()` method  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx

```
return context.BenefitsForm.Include("Dependents");
```

Another way is to enable LazyLoading on your context - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontextoptions.lazyloadingenabled.aspx

```
yourContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Comment: This is good, but is there a way I can get it to automatically include the tables that have a foreign key relationship to it without me having to explicitly explain which tables to include?